# Batch: call most recent batch file in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I saw a couple similar questions but could quite cobble together what I want. This was close because it gives me the name of the most recent batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /b c:\maps\*.bat') do set recent=%%x
echo %recent%
```

But the batch file that contains this is in, say, c:\start, so I need to get back a full pathname, not just the filename. I can then use "call" to run the batch file.

(I'm doing this on xp, incidently.)

Comment: You must know the path from when you ran the `dir` command??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use

```
 for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /b c:\maps\*.bat') do set recent=%%x
```

you positively know that the full path of the file will be `c:\maps\%%x`

---

Alternatively, if you use `dir /s` instead, it will iterate over all the existing subdirectories

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /b /s c:\maps\*.bat') do set recent=%%x
```

but with the interesting side effect of returning the full path, that will be `%%x`.

Comment: Great! I think I'll use the second method for my script.

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /b /s c:\maps\*.bat') do set recent=%%x
echo %recent%
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me than /s, which had poor performance:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /b c:\maps\*.bat') do set recent=%%~fx
```